# React Router not behaving as I would like it to

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have a webpack, react, flux, react router setup. I have these two routes:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Photos} onEnter={someAuthCheck}>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
),document.getElementById('app'));
```

When I write http://localhost:8080/login in the browser I get:

```
Cannot GET /login
```

rather than my login dialog
I am running on the webpack dev server. What am I not doing right?

My webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
    }
  },
  entry: {
    main: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "/src/client/public/",
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      { test : /\.jsx?/, include : APP_DIR, loader : 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/, loader:"url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000" },
      {test: /\.(scss|css)$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'PhotoTank',
      template: 'src/client/app/html-template.ejs',
      filename: '../index.html'
    })
  ],

  devServer: {
    //publicPath: "/src/client/public/",
     //historyApiFallBack: true,
     // progress: true,
     //hot: true,
     //inline: true,
     // https: true,
     //port: 8081,
     contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client'),
     proxy: {
       "/api": {
          target: "http://localhost:5000",
          pathRewrite: {"^/api" : ""}
       }
     }
   },

};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, if you encounter `Cannot GET` error, it is an issue with `webpack-dev-server`. From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server):

> To prepare, make sure you have a index.html file that points to your bundle. Assuming that output.filename is bundle.js:
>   `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`

So, you will have to use webpack to generate an `index.html` file first, usually called `npm run build` if you are using some boilerplate, or you have to create a separate webpack config for production build to do so.

Alternatively, just create an empty `index.html` file as instructed above.

---

There are also some problems with your `react-router` configuration:

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
```

should be

```
<Route path="login" component={Login}></Route>
```

There shouldn't be preceding slashes in children routes.

Also, you should be using `browserHistory` instead of `hashHistory` if you want to access the page at `/login`.

Comment: Regarding the 404 error: Specifically, the `historyApiFallBack` option needs to be set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `hashHistory`, so instead of

`http://localhost:8080/login`

open this:

`http://localhost:8080/#/login` it will work.

[From Doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory):

> Hash history uses the hash (#) portion of the URL, creating routes
> that look like example.com/#/some/path.

Read the difference between hashHistory and browserHistory.